# Antlr grammar unpredicted behavior

Tags: regex, antlr3

I've begun experimenting with ANTLR3 today. There seems to be a discrepency in the expressions that I use.

I want my class name to start with a capital letter, followed by mixed case letters and numbers. For instance, `Car` is valid, `8Car` is invalid.

```
CLASS_NAME : ('A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*;
```

This works fine when I test it individually. However when I use it in the following rule,

```
model
    : '~model' CLASS_NAME model_block
    ;
```

However, the `CLASS_NAME` begins to pick up class names beginning with numbers as well. In this case, ANTLR picks up `Car`, `8Car` or even `#Car` as valid tokens. I'm missing something silly. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I doubt it, `CLASS_NAME` will not match `8Car` or `#Car`. You're probably using ANTLRWorks' interpreter, which is printing errors on a UI tab you're not aware of, and incorrectly displaying the incorrect chars in the tokens. Use ANTLRWorks' debugger instead.

Comment: I'm using the ANTLR Eclipse plugin. And yes I'm using the visual interpreter.

Comment: @BartKiers, you are a genius. You are right. I just wrote a sample program to find out. Why don't you post this as an answer and let me accept it. It might help future visitors.

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer (yet) because I wasn't sure it really was the issue. Will do so in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLASS_NAME` will not match `8Car` or `#Car`. You're probably using ANTLRWorks' interpreter (or the Eclipse plugin, which uses the same interpreter), which is printing errors on a UI tab you're not aware of, and displaying the incorrect chars in the tokens. Use ANTLRWorks' debugger instead, or write a small test class yourself:

### T.g

```
grammar T;

parse : CLASS_NAME EOF;

CLASS_NAME : ('A'..'Z')('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*;
```

### Main.java

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("8Car"));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();  
  }
}
```